# User has copied other answer, I've checked if he've done it before, is that stalking?

Tags: discussion, flags, plagiarism

I've seen a short code-only answer in review queue. I've checked the question to find out that that snippet was insolently copied from accepted answer.

I've checked the user profile to find out if he's done similar offenses before and I've found the case when the copied answer get even upvoted (well, he had changed it a bit, in non-significant way - change the attributes order, HTML IDs).

But now I have a doubt if I should have done that. Is this a legitimate action to check site quality or is it stalking?

Comment: Stalking? No. Vigilanting? Maybe. Helping us make the site better and putting the point across that plagiarism must not be tolerated? Most definitely.

Comment: `(well, he had changed it a bit, in non-significant way - change the attributes order, HTML IDs)`
errr... that does sound a little weird... are you sure that he did not just write that answer by himself? How can you be sure, that he did indeed copy it?

Comment: As long as you weren't up in a tree watching him post it through his windows ... nah, you're fine.

Comment: I may check the "Activity" tab in a user's profiles when seeing: (1) a lousy answer, (2) a code only answer, (3) unexpected verbiage, (4) bad editing, (5) trivial minor editing. Fortunately, more often than not I do *not* see any immediate reason for suspicion.

Comment: Off the top of my head, if you make an account on SO, you check a box where you agree to play by it's rules. And that includes the fact that almost everything you do is public, and can be scrutinized by your fellow members.

Comment: @Theolodis I can't be sure, but that would mean that the user hasn't read existing answer, which is also unacceptable. We don't speak about answers posted in a few minutes period, it's a few months difference.

Comment: @MartijnPieters not exactly. I'm not asking about what I should do with plagiarised answers, but if I should look for them by browsing someone's profile.

Comment: @Donaudampfschifffreizeitfahrt: the post there links on to the [central FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160071/what-to-do-when-plagiarism-is-discovered) which includes: *Go hunt for more*.

Comment: Preventing plagiarized answers seems a good thing to do... however I recall reading here on Meta something like: "In the review queue we are **not** supposed to check if the answer is plagiarized or not; we should only check if it seems to be a valid attempt to answer the question. That's why we are only shown the question and the reviewed answer, but not the other answers". Was that a bad advice then?

Comment: God forbid that anyone should then go ahead and copy the same answer off the internet into their own code! I for one am outraged that there might be people on the planet writing unoriginal code.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To address this specific question: 'Is this a legitimate action to check site quality **or is it stalking**?' I checked the definition of stalking in a few places, but [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyberstalking) summarises it well.

The article cites the following behaviours (among others) as potential stalking signs:

- harassment
- false accusations
- defamation / slander / libel
- monitoring
- gathering information that may be used to threaten or harass

It doesn't sound like you are falsely accusing the user, because a flag is not in itself an accusation.

You are not naming and shaming the user, so there is no risk of defamation / slander / libel.

Although you did check the user's profile, from what you have said it wasn't repeated checking and you didn't then use the information gathered to harass the user in question.

**Conclusion:** Your described behaviour doesn't meet the accepted definitions of stalking, but if you were to continue monitoring the same user, or campaign to get them further censured, then this would cross over into stalking territory.

Comment: +1. This answers the actual question better than my answer does.

Answer (score 18):

If you seriously suspect that a user is engaged in plagiarism, that is something for a mod to look at.

But before you flag, consider - sometimes there is only one real answer to a question, and  multiple users post very similar answers independent from each other. (As an example, take a look at all the questions where beginning Java programmers are trying to compare strings using `==`...)

Flag only if you have serious suspicion that a user is acting in bad faith - but if you do have that strong suspicion, **do** flag!

So, you did right. You found something that looked like plagiarism, but before flagging, decided to see if there was a pattern. Only after that did you flag.

Comment: I would never flag a plagiarism if it was a few minutes' difference. But it was posted a few months after.